# What should I prefer using JPA - pure SQL or JPQL and how to create/delete table using JPQL and Entity

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, jpql

I am using ***entityManager*** in my ***DAO***.

To ***create*** table, i am using:

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists cats (name varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, age int NOT NULL);
```

To ***delete*** table i am using:

```
String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE examples";
```

To ***execute*** it i am using:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql).executeQuery();
```

How can i do ***the same*** using ***JPQL*** (i have an ***@Entity*** for it if needed)?

Which method should i prefer - ***createNativeQuery()*** +***SQL*** OR ***createQuery()*** +***JPQL***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create a table as [jpql specification](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html) says. When it comes to querying, it depends.

Jpql advantages:

1. Jpql takes advantage of mapping (lazy / eager loading, relatinships) - it uses what you have already defined. In SQL you would have to map the result somehow.
2. Queries can be stored in cache to provide better performance.
3. Persistence context doesn't need to be flushed before query.
4. You can use IDE to change the name of the entity together with queries. They are easier to maintain.
5. DBMS agnostic - you can change database any time, it'll work (this can also be a disadvantage - the syntax is limited by sql standards).

SQL advantages:

1. You can use vendor specific dialect, it overcomes the shortcomings of jpql validation.
2. DML operations are supported, such as cropping or creating table. Also indices and partitioning.
3. You have greater control of queries to db.

To sum up: **unless you need vendor specific queries that would possibly ease implementation and/or improve performance, jpql should be the choice**. Schema modeling shouldn't be done at runtime.

Comment: I don't know if it's an advantage or not. It depends. Look at 1. advantage of SQL. You can take advantage of dbms but you don't have to, if you want sql to follow some universal specs. But changing database in running system is not frequent. I'll edit the answer;) btw. do you really think, that THIS is the most important one? not for example ORM?

Comment: Do I ? Yes, but then that comes down to my own perspective, of writing portable applications with no specific target database. It's all opinion-based clearly based on priorities and perspectives. Which is why a question of this nature is out of bounds for SO